# Understanding Java Setters And Getters

Tags: java, setter, tapestry, getter

I'm working on a Java project I didn't code, written with Tapestry 4. Here's an example of some code:

```
@Persist
public abstract String getParentClientId();
public abstract void setParentClientId(String str);
```

My knowledge of Java is limited. I'm accustomed to seeing getters return something and setters, well, set something. There's no {} used to define these methods and no code between them like I expect. Is there some convention I'm missing? Perhaps getParentClientId() implicitly returns the value of ParentClientId, or something of the like? Any info you have would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

those are `abstract methods` that's why they dont have any implementation. To know more about the abstract class and methods see [Oracle's documentation on Abstract Methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html):

> An abstract method is a method that is declared without an implementation (without braces, and followed by a semicolon), like this:
>
> ```
> abstract void moveTo(double deltaX, double deltaY);
> ```
>
> When an abstract class is subclassed, the subclass usually provides implementations for all of the abstract methods in its parent class. However, if it does not, the subclass must also be declared abstract.

Comment: I'm out of flags for the day, so instead, I just edited this to bring in the contents from the link so that if the link breaks this is still useful. When Sun sold out to Oracle, I believe there were many links that broke when Oracle moved everything around, so link-rot can and has been be a real problem on Stack Overflow before. Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Thanks. This helps. I understand the subclass concept, but I see these methods being called elsewhere in the same .java file where the methods are defined. How can they be called/used with no definition? I can't find anywhere else in the project that they are defined with code. This sounds like a basic Java concept that I'm missing, correct?

Comment: Yep, think of it like this. You have a Person class. A person can run(). But you also have an OldPerson subclass and a YoungPerson subclass. Since the YoungPerson can run faster then the OldPerson, and since in your program you want to choose one or the other, you simply choose not to implement run() for the Person class by making the method abstract. Thus, you never really instantiate a Person, you just instantiate a YoungPerson or an OldPerson, but you don't need to worry about reimplementing methods that will stay the same.

Answer (score 0):

typical implementation of setter and getter is:

```
public String getParentClientId() { return parentClientId;}

public void setParentClientId(String str){ parentClientId = str;}
```

If method have `abstract` modifier means that it should be implmeneted in subclass

Answer (score 0):

Your methods are abstract, and you must to realiaze tham)

Answer (score 0):

The methods are defined as abstract hence there is no code with it.

Maybe some tapestry API will implement these abstract method by creating dynamic classes as you have used @Persist for getParentClientId(). If these methods are working in your code then this must be the case.

Answer (score 0):

Those are abstract classes. They are used to define methods that have to be present on any instance of that class, but are different for each subclass. They are actually defined in subclasses.
Of course no objects of the class that defines the abstract methods can be created, as it wouldn't have an implementation of that methods. Therefore, only abstract classes can include abstract methods - and one can never create instances of abstract classes.

Answer (score 0):

I 'm not a Tapestry 4 user but, as far as I know Tapestry 4 used a lot of abstract method declarations to hook functionality you don't have to code (as getters/setters for example).

Afterwards Tapestry 4 would create a new class in runtime that inherits your class and implements some of the abstract methods you declared (based in certain Tapestry 4 convention).

I 'm a Tapestry 5 user, and in this new version abstract methods are not required by the framework they 've changed the way the runtime created classes are created (they 're now using the Plastic framework, and previously javassist) in order to avoid those rare abstract declarations in favor of use of brand new Annotations.

If you have the time to migrate to T5 don't doubt it!